# Single letter being prepended to JSON records from NIFI JSONRecordSetWriter

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-nifi

I'm fairly new to NiFi and Kafka and I have been struggling with this problem for a few days.  I have a NiFi data flow that ends with JSON records being being published to a Kafka topic using PublishKafkaRecord_2_0 processor configured with a JSONRecordSetWriter service as the writer.  Everything seems to work great: messages are published to Kafka and looking at the records in the flow file after being published look like well-formed JSON.  Though, when consuming the messages on the command line I see that they are prepended with a  single letter.  Trying to read the messages with ConsumeKafkaRecord_2_0 configured with a JSONTreeReader and of course see the error [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aQQOd.png).

As I've tried different things the letter has changed: it started with an "h", then "f" (when configuring a JSONRecordSetWriter farther upstream and before being published to Kafka), and currently a "y".

I can't figure out where it is coming from.  I suspect it is caused by the JSONRecordSetWriter but not sure.  My configuration for the writer is [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vSgje.png) and nothing looks unusual to me.

I've tried debugging by creating different flows. I thought the issue might be with my Avro schema and tried replacing that.  I'm out of things to try, does anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have the "Schema Write Strategy" set to "Confluent Schema Reference" this is telling the writer to write the confluent schema id reference at the beginning of the content of the message, so likely what you are seeing is the bytes of that.

If you are using the confluent schema registry then this is correct behavior and those values need to be there for the consuming side to determine what schema to use.

If you are not using confluent schema registry when consuming these messages, just choose one of the other Schema Write Strategies.

Comment: smh.  Once I changed the write strategy to Do Not Write Schema, it worked perfectly.  Thanks for pointing this out Bryan, who knows how much more time I would have spent on something so simple.